# Simple redirect 301 using htaccess not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I am trying to redirect:

```
website.com/test.html?view=test
```

to

```
website.com/test/
```

using this code but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} view=test
RewriteRule ^test\.html$ /test/? [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)view=test($|&)
RewriteRule ^website\.com/test\.html$ /website.com/test/?&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Comment: Hey @Jeffrey, that sucks. What are the actual URLs you need rewritten? It is a lot easier to work with the correct URLs